# PHP Is removing the zero at the end of my number value

Tags: php

This is in Laravel, which probably isn't relevant.

```
<?php $totalprice = 0 ?> @foreach ($items as $item) <?php $totalprice = $totalprice + $item->net_price ?> @endforeach
```

$item->net_price could start at 884.80 for example but if it ends on 1204.30 it will display as 1204.3. As this is a cost calculation I would prefer that zero to stay on the end.

Simple question but I'm a noob :( How do I fix this? Can't seem to find on Google.

Comment: `number_format($number, 2, '.', '');` ?

Comment: You dont want the zero at the end?

Comment: Any my offered solution (comment) didn't help?

Comment: BTW, `<?php $totalprice = $totalprice + $item->net_price ?>` => `$totalprice += $item->net_price`

Comment: Yes your solution worked. I can't select it as the answer though as you've written it as a comment! Thanks and thanks for that second tip I thought there was probably a more concise way of writing that.

Comment: If so, i'll post it as an answer for your approval.

Comment: Can you please upvote and approve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the money_format() function (http://php.net/money_format)

For example:

```
class items{}

$item1 = new items();
$item1->net_price = "14.6";
$item2 = new items();
$item2->net_price = "12.50";

$items = [$item1, $item2];

//display a '£' symbol
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8');

foreach ($items as $item){
    $totalprice = 0; 
    $totalprice = $totalprice + $item->net_price;
    echo money_format('%.2n',$totalprice) . "\n";
}
```

Based on your original question the following should work:

```
@foreach ($items as $item) 
<?php 
$totalprice = 0;
$totalprice = $totalprice + $item->net_price;
$totalprice = money_format('%.2', $totalprice);
?> 
@endforeach
```

I moved the $totalprice variable into the loop so that it gets reset to zero before it is used.

NB PHP needs to be 4.3+ and the server needs to be capable of strfmon.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `number_format()`.

```
echo number_format(100000000, 2, '.', '');
```

If you want the `,` separator format then just add `,` to the last parameter. Will get details [here](http://php.net/number_format)

Answer (score 0):

In continuation of my comment to the question, you should use the [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) function.

> string number_format ( float $number , int $decimals = 0 , string
>   $dec_point = "." , string $thousands_sep = "," )

So, this usage would do the work:

```
number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```

In your code:

```
<?php $totalprice = 0 ?> 
@foreach ($items as $item) <?php $totalprice += $item->net_price ?> @endforeach
<?php echo number_format($totalprice, 2, '.', ''); ?>
```